# How to tell what service pack for Microsoft Commerce Server 2000 is installed?

Tags: windows-server-2000

We have ancient Windows 2000 Server box running Commerce Server 2000.  I'm trying to determine what service pack the Commerce Server has and I don't see any way to do that from the Management Console.  I know the latest service pack for that release of Commerce Server is [SP3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297216), but this server is so rickety that I'm afraid to break something by attempting to install a service pack that may already be in place.  How can I tell what service pack for the Commerce Server (if any) is installed on this machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found there is a log file placed in the root Commerce Server program directory (which is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Commerce Server\` on this box) called `CS2KSP3.log`.  That file indicates the date of service pack 3 installation.  This solves my immediate issue, though a more concrete answer would be appreciated.